# Ubuntu 20.04 shutdown stuck on blinking cursor

Tags: grub2, 20.04, shutdown

So, not a new install, used it for a while and had issues with this:

[image: error message during boot]

This happened and stopped and happened and stopped, I don't know why. Every time it happened, I would shutdown with:

```
shutdown -h
```

and it would get stuck on that screen.

Now it is still happening, but only with a black screen and blinking cursor:

[image: black screen and blinking cursor]

I tried pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, which made the cursor disappear, but nothing else happened. I also edited my GRUB settings using the following, but this is as far as my knowledge goes:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=force"
```

I get no text in this screen or anything.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was cause by my Bluetooth 5 dongle. If that's the case, just unplug the dongle during restart.